# Asynchronous Message-Passing and Microservices

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, microservices

I am planning the develop of a microservice based architecture application and I decided to use kafka for the internal communicaton while I was reading the book *Microservice Architecture by Ronnie Mitra; Matt McLarty; Mike Amundsen; Irakli Nadareishvili* where they said:

> letting microservices directly interact with message brokers (such as
>   RabbitMQ, etc.) is rarely a good idea. If two microservices are
>   directly communicating via a message-queue channel, they are sharing a
>   data space (the channel) and we have already talked, at length, about
>   the evils of two microservices sharing a data space. Instead, what we
>   can do is encapsulate message-passing behind an independent
>   microservice that can provide message-passing capability, in a loosely
>   coupled way, to all interested microservices.

[image]

I am using Netflix Eureka for Service registration and discovery, Zuul as edge server and Hystrix. 
Said so, in practice, how can I implement that kind of microservice? How can I make my microservices indipendent from the communcation channel ( in this case Kafka)? 
Actually I'm directly interacting with the channel, so I don't have an extra layer between my publishers/subscribers and kafka.

**UPDATE 06/02/2018**

to be more precise, we have a couple of microservices: one is publishing news on a topic (activemq, kafka...) and the other microservice is subscribed on that topic and doing some operations on the messages that are coming through. So we have these services that are coupled to the message broker (to the channel)... we have the the message broker's apis "embedeed" on our code and for example, if we want to change the message broker we have to change all the microservices that made use of the message broker's api. So, they are suggesting to use a microservice(in the picture I assume is the Events Hub) that is the "dispatcher" of the various messages. In this way it is the only component that interacts with the channel.

Comment: Can you explain this "If two microservices are directly communicating via a message-queue channel, they are sharing a data space (the channel) "

Comment: @techagrammer I updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A general foreword - Don't do it if you don't need it. Introducing a queue system can be a big improvement if you are dealing with high number of events and events backing up issues etc. But if you don't face any issues you are probably better off with the lower complexity of a direct service communication.

Back to your question - It sounds like you want to abstract your communication with the queue because you are worried about the effort for replacing the queue with a different system - Is that correct?

In this case you can either do what you proposed - Develop a new service in the middle. This comes with all the baggage of a physical service (including deployment, scaling, etc).

Or the second alternative is to write a client library that abstracts the queue the way you want and allows you to reuse it in all services requiring to participate in the queue. This way you don't have to physically deploy another service for this purpose but you are still in full control of what your interface to the queue should look like and you have a single piece of code to incorporate changes (at least toward the direction of the queue). This would work given you are sure the app-facing side of the library can be stable enough.

But, again, don't do any of those in the first iteration when you are not sure you need all the complexity. (Over-engineering is a dangerous thing)

Comment: +1 for introducing a wrapper over communication channel, it exactly gives the flexibility of switching between JMS.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a Interface lets say "Queue" which provide all functionalities which you want from Kafka or RabbitMQ, the create diff. impl like KafkaQueue and RabbitMQQueue of the Queue interface and inject the right impl which you want to use in your system.

In this your if new queue system is used , your existing code will not be changed

Creating another microservice is an extra overhead in this case

Answer (score 0):

In a service architecture proper way to make your code independent out of constraints of communication channel is by having properly modeled self-sufficient messages. Historic examples would be WSDL in document mode, EDIFACT, HATEOAS etc. From this point of view microservices with spring-boot and kafka are just different implementation of same old thing done since mainframes ruled the world.

Essentially if you take a view of your app as blackbox asynchronous server; everything app does is receives events and produces new ones. It should not matter how events are raised within app. Http requests, xml within jms messages, json in kafka, whatever - all those things are just a way to pass events and business layer of application should respond only to a content of events.

So business layer is usually structured around some custom model/domain which are delivered as payload. Business layer is invoked/triggered by listener/producer layer which talks to communcation channel (kafka listener, http listener etc..). Aside from logging and enforcing security you should not have communication channel logic in app. I have seen unfortunate examples of business logic driven by by originating jms connection or parsing url of request. If you ever have this in your code you have failed to properly structure your code.

However that is easier to say than to implement. Some people are good at this level of modeling, and some never learn.

And there is no other way to learn but to try and fail.